# WPF performance issue when resizing the window with lots of controls

Tags: wpf, performance, controls, resize, window

I have a WPF window that contains a fancy image with roughly 200 controls (derived from buttons), all of which use one of my 5 templates (paths, shadow effects, etc).  Agreed, it is a heavy window to draw.  I can live with that.

My problem comes from resizing the window.  Maximize/Restore take about 1-2 seconds, but manually dragging the bottom-left corner causes the system to hang for about 5-10 seconds.  In that delay, the window is black & contains partial leftovers until the final result is shown.  It looks amateurish and *that*, I can't live with.

Remote connection : using a remote account, I found that the window resize always takes 1-2 seconds, but doesn't draw the "intermediate" stages while I'm dragging the window borders.  The result is as snappy as I would expect.

My conclusion is this: It's the redraws *during* the resize that are bottlenecks.

The inevitable question is this : how can I prevent redrawing the window until the resize is finished?

Thanks in advance for any ideas...

Comment: +1 For a good question even though you have 200 controls which is not good. :)

Comment: Thanks ;)  It sounds like bad design, but it's really a very complex interface.  Rocket science, so to speak.

Comment: "The inevitable question is this : how can I prevent redrawing the window until the resize is finished?"  -Remote desktop ;-)

Comment: Nice try Firoso ;)  But my interface is already the 'remote' solution to using the actual hardware instruments...  I'm beginning to think WPF is not designed for interfaces that go beyond 2-3 controls at a time.  Like simple configuration dialogs.  Anyone care to prove me wrong?  I would love to stand corrected!

Answer (score 4):

> @Seb:  I'm beginning to think WPF is
>   not designed for interfaces that go
>   beyond 2-3 controls at a time

Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend should be good counterexamples. Though Visual Studio sometimes freezes the bottleneck is definitely not in the WPF rendering.

> @Seb: The inevitable question is this : how
>   can I prevent redrawing the window
>   until the resize is finished?

Simply set the window's content visibility to `Visibility.Collapsed` before the resize/maximize and make it visible afterwards. Though I think you asked the wrong question. Here is the right one

**How to make my controls measure/arrange extremely fast?**

And to answer it you should take a look at your code. Maybe you intensively use dependency properties in the measuring/arrange algorithm? Or maybe you picked wrong panels (e.g. Grid is slower than Canvas)? Or maybe... I stop guessing here :).

By the way, it's always better to launch your app under profiler and prove the bottleneck rather than assuming the place where it might be. Check [Eqatec Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/Home.aspx) it's free yet powerful enough. VS 2010 also offers nice profiling features, though it's far from being free. And you may want to check [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Comment: All right.  Finally managed to try your approach.  We are hiding some expensive layers and it greatly helps.  I think we're pushing WPF to its limits... from what I hear, dotnet 4 & msdev 2010 & blend 4 might have optimizations we're not getting from dotnet 3.5 & msdev 2008 & blend 3.  We'll get there.  Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Let me know how this works... I am assuming that your root visual item is stretching to horizontally and vertically to fill your window with auto height/width. Get rid of the Auto height/width. On app start up set the dimensions of the root element. There is a FrameworkElements have a [size changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Register for this on your `Application.Current.MainWindow` (maybe be a typo, that was from memory). Whenever this event fires, start a timer with a small interval. If you get another resize while the timer is running, ignore it and reset the timer. Once the timer fires, you now know the new size the user desires and that they have (at least for a short period) stopped resizing the window.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice workaround, but we need to show at least something during the resize, otherwise the user doesn't know what the end result will be until he releases the mouse...  I'll keep this in mind tho.  Might prove to be a handy workaround some day.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Ragepotato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649694/wpf-performance-issue-when-resizing-the-window-with-lots-of-controls/4651198#4651198) and your comment about needing to see roughly what the interface would look like *while* resizing, as long as you don't have your objects dynamically re-locating themselves (like a `Wrap Panel`) - you could take a screenshot of the window contents and fill your frame with it.

Set it to stretch both height and width, and you'd get a (slightly fuzzy) idea of what a particular size would be. It wouldn't be live while resizing, but for those few seconds that probably wouldn't matter..